# Safe to use Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm about to create a huge website which will have a lot of visitors. However I'd like to add effect to this site with jQuery. My only problem is that, I'm afraid that a lot of people will have JS disabled and they'll not be able to see the content, or it will be corrupted in some way.

Can someone please tell me if it is safe to use Javascript nowdays, or I should afraid of people who don't have JS enabled?

I would also be interested that how much internet users are using JS enabled Browsers.

Comment: Related discussion at Programmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149021/should-i-still-make-my-site-work-in-non-javascript-capable-browsers

Comment: Good programmers always ensure for both. You can add effects with javascript but remember to allow non-javascript users to use the site. Also there's many things that can be done server-side and should be. Do client-side just what really needs it.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close but don't feel bad, it's just that this question is frequently asked in various forms. What I recommend is: make your website completely work **before** adding any javascript, and then you can start making effects. This is harder, but think about the poor blind guy or the one using a mobile phone (or whatever reason that makes your site not work, such as using Internet Explorer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to use JavaScript. Less then 1% of all users have JavaScript disabled. This is  a report from Yahoo from 2010: http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/many-users-javascript-disabled-14121.html.

In fact few browser stats do not even represent this metric as the value is irrelevant.
Good web design practices should allow your site content to be accessible even if JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: Yeah, I've already saw this. I was just thinking, if we see look at Google Analytics, it also uses JS to detect if an user is on your site or not, right? So basically everyone who's been detected, are using JS. So should we actually bother to pay attention to non-js users?

Comment: I do not know how Analytics track users with and without JS. Content should be accessible with or without js.

Comment: @Radical_Activity yes, Google Analytics only tracks users with JavaScript enabled. I'm not sure if you've mixed this up so I'll point it out just in case: the "analytics" talked about by Yahoo doesn't refer to Google Analytics; it's their own server logs. So they will be tracking every user, regardless of whether JavaScript is enabled. The 1-2% figure is probably accurate (though out-of-date now; I imagine it is shrinking quite quickly with the growth of online tools like Google Docs)

Comment: Thanks Dave. Good point. Stats track this kind of data at server level not client.

Answer (score 0):

Use [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com). It checks if JavaScript is enabled in someone's browser and lets you style your content according to it.

Comment: Modernizr doesn't detect if JavaScript is *enabled*, it detects if individual JavaScript/HTML5/CSS features are available in the browser, using JavaScript. By definition you can't use JavaScript to detect if JavaScript is available.

Comment: @Juhana actually that's the easiest test ever; `<script>alert('JavaScript is Enabled!')</script>`

Comment: @Juhana I was talking about the class that modernizr adds to the html tag for checking js is enabled.

Comment: @Dave True, but you don't need a library for that!

Comment: @akash4eva You really don't need Modernizr to do that.

Comment: @Juhana, I know but I wanted to direct the guy who asked the question to a kickstart application for his project. No bad intention for asking him to get lots of scripts/libraries on his site.